# How to transform data with feature variables that use, e.g., Top 10%, Top 5, >5, <=2?

Tags: encoding, transformation

I get results back from a program that I want to see the Top 7 companies (a filter if you will) whose current divided yield is x%. Or whose historical dividend growth is >5%. My question is how to input/transform those symbols ('>', 'Top #', 'top %') into a spreadsheet for later analysis. Those are the feature variables. One-hot encoding? Hopefully not, but I'm at a loss.

Example:

```
Screen   | Volume >250,000 | Volume <100,000 | Final criteria selection Top 10% |
         | --------        |        -------- | ---------------                  |
Screen v1|      1          |             0   |                1                 |
Screen v2|      0          |             1   |                0                 |
```

Hopefully that is clear, if not I'll try again.

the only way I can think of is one-hot encoding/binary, but I'm sure (I hope) there is a better alternative.